# SpringMVC <mvc:resources/> Spring Xml mode validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm placed `statics` folder `css, js, images`, wanted add `sources` on web-app

the xml seem can't be resolved.
report error is:

> Cant resolve location `statics`, Spring Xml mode validaton

after open browser checked `Sources`, can't load `js, images`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.f.dao, com.f.controller, com.f.service, com.f.advice"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/statics/" location="statics"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/users/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: where your static folder.. show the directory of your project

Comment: A standard Maven folder structure, puts the static resources like js and css files into the webapp\resources folder.

Comment: and use `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/"`

Comment: look this example you will get idea :https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: oh, I'm create `resources` folder on webapp and move `statics` under `resources`, error is: `Cannot resolve location '/resources/statics'/  Spring Xml model validation